# Return keyword of string if found in dataframe columns

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a string. I need to find if the keywords in that string is present in my dataframe.

If present, I need to return that keyword back.

**String:**

```
question="Joe is Available"
question=question.upper()
str_list=question.split()
str_list
```

Out[107]:

```
['JOE', 'IS', 'AVAILABLE']
```

**Dataframe:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Person1":("Ash","Joe","Harry"),"Person2":("Abe","Lisa","Katty",),"Person3":("Sam","Max","Stone")})
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())


Person1 Person2 Person3
ASH     ABE     SAM
JOE     LISA    MAX
HARRY   KATTY   STONE
```

**My Attempt:**

```
return_field=""
for x in str_list:
    print(x)
    for i in df.iterrows():
        if(df.str.contains(x)):
            return_field=x
```

Gives me AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

**Expected Output**

Since Joe is present in the dataframe, it should return me back "Joe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this repeatedly, you may wish to hash your values via `set`. Also, you can use `map` with `str.upper` to convert dataframe values to upper case<sup>1</sup>:

```
str_all = set(map(str.upper, df.values.ravel()))

question = "Joe is Available"
str_search = set(question.upper().split())

res = str_search & str_all

# {'JOE'}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You *can* use `pd.DataFrame.apply` + `lambda`, but this isn't recommended. String operations via `pd.Series.str` are, currently, notoriously slow. Adding a `lambda` loop on top makes it worse.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [741]: [x for x in str_list if x in df.values]
Out[741]: ['JOE']
```